# Probability CDF question on highest number of marbles pulled out

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I'm kinda stuck on this problem. Here goes: 
An urn contains n marbles, numbered 1, 2, . . . , n. Suppose k < n marbles
are drawn from it at random without replacement. Let X denote the highest number
that has been pulled out.
Determine the Cummulative Distribution F of X. Hint: calculate P(X ≤ x) for x ∈ {k, k + 1, . . . , n} .

I don't quite get what the question asks, why is the number of marbles you pick out a random variable? You choose how many you will pick out, no?
I don't really know how to do this, obviously P(X<=x)= 0 if x<0 and P(X<=x)= 1 if x=n. But I can't find a function whose sum over all x will add to 1. Any hints? I tried P=(n-k)/n for k

Comment: The number of marbles one picks out is not random but the marks on the marbles one picks are. And X is the highest mark on the k marbles one chooses. Can you solve the exercise now that this is clear?

Comment: By marks do you mean each marble in the urn is marked 1,2,3,4, etc? Or do you mean if the person chooses 5 marbles, then it could be that he chose marble marked 3 and a marble marked 7 say?  Thanks.

Comment: Is my comment ambiguous? By marks I mean marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We draw without replacement $k$ marbles out of an urn of $n$ uniquely labelled marbles, marked from $1$ to $n$, and record the highest label of all the marbles draw as our random variable $X$.

*Note:* The support of $X$ must therefore be: $\{k, , , n\}$

The Cumulative Probability Function of $X$ is $\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)$, and this is the probability of selecting $k$ marbles such that *all of* their labels are *at most* $x$ out of all the ways to select $k$ marbles from $n$.

$$\mathsf P(X\leqslant x) = \dbinom{\Box}{\Box}\bigg/\dbinom{\Box}{\Box} \qquad \text{when } x\in\{k,,,x\}$$

*Hint:* How many marbles have labels that are at most $x$?

Comment: Thanks, as for your hint, the number of marbles having labels that are at most x is x right? So P(X<=x)= (x choose k)/ (n choose k) ?

Comment: $\checkmark$ You got it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, as for your hint, the number of marbles having labels that are at most x is x right?
So P(X<=x)= (k choose x)/ (n choose k) ?